# Codeigniter: query not properly printed

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have implemented a query to show the number of rows of my table, the query has been implemented in the model and the function has been called in controller class, but it throws the next text:

> CI_DB_mysqli_result Object ( [conn_id] => mysqli Object (
>   [affected_rows] => 1 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 -
>   $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $ [client_version] =>
>   50011 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] =>
>   [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 1 [host_info] => localhost
>   via TCP/IP [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] =>
>   5.5.5-10.1.21-MariaDB [server_version] => 50505 [stat] => Uptime: 8603 Threads: 1 Questions: 1350 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 38 Flush tables: 1
>   Open tables: 32 Queries per second avg: 0.156 [sqlstate] => 00000
>   [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 61 [warning_count] => 0 )
>   [result_id] => mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0
>   [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )
>   [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( )
>   [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] =>
>   [row_data] => )

**Database**

[image]

**Model**

```
<?php

class Entregas_Model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code
        $this->load->database();
    }

    //Para obtener el número de filas 
    //y así determinar el número de plazas
    public function get_rows($idCarga) {
        $this->db->select('COUNT(idCarga)');
        $this->db->from('entregas');
        $this->db->join('intervalosHorarios', 'entregas.idCarga = intervalosHorarios.idIntervaloHorario');
        //$this->db->on('entregas.idCarga = intervalosHorarios.idCarga');
        $this->db->where('entregas.idIntervaloHorario', $idCarga);

        $q = $this->db->get();
        //$q = $q->result_array();
        print_r($q);
        return $q;
    }

}
```

**Controller(short version)**

```
  public function entregas_lista($idCarga) {

        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        $this->Entregas_Model->get_rows($idCarga);
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use $this->db->last_query();  instead of print_r($q)

Comment: instead `$this->db->get()` use `$this->db->count_all_results()` if you want to have count, else if you want records use `$this->db->get()->result()` and if you want just one row, use `$this->db->get()->row()`

Comment: change $this->db->select('COUNT(idCarga)'); to $this->db->select('COUNT(idCarga) as total_records'); then print this $q = $this->db->get()->row()->total_records;

Comment: @HosseinShahsahebi Jose is already couting the result in " COUNT(idCarga) " no need of $this->db->count_all_results()

Comment: @RanjeetSingh So he should remove the `select` part in order to simplicity

Comment: I think count is faster than querying whole data set @HosseinShahsahebi.

Comment: Since you get `[affected_rows] => 1` the query is probably giving you what you want. I'd say do as @RanjeetSingh says.

Comment: Yes @PerEnström he alway get [affected_rows] => 1.

Comment: @RanjeetSingh It's important to mention that `count_all_results` wont get all records and count them, instead it will generate `SELECT COUNT(*)` for you

Comment: @HosseinShahsahebi Great then

Comment: Thank you everyone! It's working fine now! I have implemented @HosseinShahsahebi answer so he can post the solution and I'll give it as correct. (one more thing: if i have 3 rows it returns 2 rows, i supose that it is counting from 0, how can i fix that?)

Comment: @Jose Thank dude, Are u sure about this kind of counting, it wont count from 0. this is new problem which I did not see before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to simplicity you should change your `Query Builder` a little bit as below:

```
$this->db->from('entregas');
$this->db->join(/*Join Parameters*/);
$this->db->where('entregas.idIntervaloHorario', $idCarga);
$q = $this->db->count_all_results(); //q should contain integer that represent your records count
```

In other situation that you want to get one record or all records you should add another function to `get` as below:

```
$this->db->get()->row(); //return 1 row
$this->db->get()->result(); //return all matched rows
```

Comment: Come back to the trouble... after adding new items the query always return 1, this is crazy, i have tried all :(

Comment: Solved! in order to make a better query: 
`public function get_rows($idCarga) {

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM entregas LEFT JOIN intervaloshorarios on entregas.idCarga = intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario
        WHERE entregas.idIntervaloHorario = ' . $idCarga . ';');

        echo $query->num_rows();


        return $query;
    }`

Comment: That's not a good idea, because you get all rows and count them cause your server to be involved a lot

Comment: Better with (left join added)? 
`$this->db->from('entregas');
$this->db->join(/*Join Parameters with LEFT JOIN added*/);
$this->db->where('entregas.idIntervaloHorario', $idCarga);
$q = $this->db->count_all_results();`

Comment: Reason could be a problem or other type of issue in your join, take a look and test it without join

Answer (score 1):

Use below line to see information related to database:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

It will show all the database query running in current call stack. Or you can use below line after the query run, to print only query.

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

Comment: I was looking for something like @Hossein answer but thank you anyway!